# MySQL injection vulnerability for Joomla 1.5/2.5/3

Tags: php, mysql, security, joomla

Yesterday in Joomla VEL has been announced a vulnerability in a component that I would rather not mention here in order not to spread this information, and that I would like to fix.

This vulnerability applies also to Joomla 1.5 version of the component, but the component team only fixed the vulnerability in Joomla 2.5 and 3.x versions. I am going to post here the function that has been modified in Joomla 2.5 and Joomla 3, and I would  like to know if I can modify the same function in the same way or in a different way in order to be compatible with Joomla 1.5 version.

In the following example, please consider that I will edit the code in order to remove the name of the component.

So, original function in Joomla 3 was:

```
function _setExtension($option) {
    static $components = array();

    if (!isset($components[$option])) {
        $filter = ComponentUtility::getSkippedComponents();
        $component = ComponentDatabase::loadResult("SELECT `element` FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` NOT IN ({$filter}) AND `element` = '{$option}'");
```

This has been fixed in the following way:

```
function _setExtension($option) {
    static $components = array();

    if (!isset($components[$option])) {
        $filter = ComponentUtility::getSkippedComponents();
        $option = ComponentDatabase::escape($option);
        $component = ComponentDatabase::loadResult("SELECT `element` FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` NOT IN ({$filter}) AND `element` = '{$option}'");
```

In Joomla 2.5, the original function was:

```
function _setExtension($option) {
    static $components = array();

    if (!isset($components[$option])) {
        $filter = ComponentUtility::getSkippedComponents();
        $component = ComponentDatabase::loadResult("SELECT `element` FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` NOT IN ({$filter}) AND `element` = '{$option}'");
```

This has been fixed in the following way:

```
function _setExtension($option) {
    static $components = array();

    if (!isset($components[$option])) {
        $filter = ComponentUtility::getSkippedComponents();
        $option = ComponentDatabase::getEscaped($option);
        $component = ComponentDatabase::loadResult("SELECT `element` FROM `#__extensions` WHERE `type` = 'component' AND `element` NOT IN ({$filter}) AND `element` = '{$option}'");
```

In Joomla 1.5, the original function is:

```
function _setExtension($option) {
    static $components = array();

    if (!isset($components[$option])) {
        $filter = "'com_sef', 'com_sh404sef', 'com_joomfish', 'com_config', 'com_media', 'com_installer', 'com_templates', 'com_plugins', 'com_modules', 'com_cpanel', 'com_cache', 'com_messages', 'com_menus', 'com_massmail', 'com_languages', 'com_users'";
        $component = ComponentDatabase::loadResult('SELECT `option` FROM `#__components` WHERE `parent` = "0" AND `option` NOT IN ('.$filter.') AND `option` = "'.$option.'"');
```

And this has not been fixed.

So, in Joomla 3, the fixing line was:

```
            $option = ComponentDatabase::escape($option);
```

In Joomla 2.5 the fixing line was:

```
        $option = ComponentDatabase::getEscaped($option);
```

And in Joomla 1.5? How can I properly escape the option parameter and fix the function?

Comment: Can you see if `ComponentDatabase::getEscaped` is available yourself? Or what the equivalent is in 1.5? I expect docs should be available for legacy versions.

Comment: i made a regex search in Joomla 1.5 files, and I see that the `getEscaped` is avaiable in the same component, but I don't know the right syntax, if it would be the same as 2.5 version or not.

Comment: for example, another file of the same component in Joomla 1.5 version has the `$result = self::$_dbo->getEscaped($text, $extra);`

Comment: because I don't know how to do this, I am only trying to fix this vulnerability myself but... I have not a good knowledge.. so... I am trying to get some light here in StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ComponentDatabase` is not a class that belongs to Joomla by default, therefore it belongs to your component.

[getEscaped](http://docs.joomla.org/API15:JDatabaseMySQL/getEscaped) is however a function that belongs to Joomla 1.5 which simple gets an escaped string from the database.

Assuming that `ComponentDatabase` also belongs to the Joomla 1.5 compatible version of this component, should should be able to do the same as the other fixes:

```
$option = ComponentDatabase::getEscaped($option);
```

If `ComponentDatabase` does not belong to the Joomla 1.5 version of the component, then copy it over from the Joomla 2.5 version (not 3.x) and bare in mind that you might have to make some tweaks to it.

Comment: yes, `ComponentDatabase` belongs to the Joomla 1.5 version of the component, and I see other files with the `getEscaped` thing, but some of them has the `$this->` before the variable, well, I am not a programmer...

Comment: so I will simply copy the `$option = ComponentDatabase::getEscaped($option);` inside the Joomla 1.5 function and I should be fine, right?

Comment: any way to contact you in order to tell you the exact code and the component name?

Comment: First try adding `$option = ComponentDatabase::getEscaped($option);` as has been done for the other versions to see what the result is. Only problem being is that I would not be able to test an SQL injection as this is something I do not have experience with